# Storing data across Fragment and Activity life cycles in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, storage

I need to store an `array` of Custom Objects to populate a `ListView` in android. I fetch the data to populate the `ListView` in a `Fragment` that is a part of `NavigationDrawer` (The Fragments are replaced frequently). The next time I start the `Fragment`, data is fetched again. I want this data to be persistent even when I go to another `Activity` and come back.
         I'm not considering using a `database` as I don't need the data to be restored when the user restarts the app. I just need the data as long as the user is actively using the app.

**I've considered the following methods:**

1. Singleton class
2. Subclassing the Application class
3. Saving the Instance state in the Fragment/Activity

Is it fine to store an array of 2000 objects in the Application subclass? Is there a better methos to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't consider using the Singleton Class, if you want your data to be persistent.The best Android practice to store persistent data are :

```
1.Application Preferences
2.Files
3.contentProviders
4.SQLite DB
```

You can read more about it here : http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html

Comment: I don't want the data to be persistent when the user closes and reopens the app. I just need a method to save data across the Fragment and Activity life cycles. 

 1->  In fragment1, Data fetched here and ListView populated.
 2->  Fragment1 replaced by Fragment 2 within same Activity (Fragment1 destroyed). If I go back to Fragment1, I'll have to refetch data.


If I move to another Activity and get back to the Fragment Activity, I'll have to refetch data again.

**All I want is, a method to store data across the Fragment life cycle, the data should be cleared on exiting the app.**

Comment: Ok, then you should have a look at the "Non-Persistent Objects" part explained in the link mentioned above.

Comment: I'm considering doing some thing like this:  http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

I need to store an array of Custom Objects of size upto 2000. Isn't the Application subclass used to store a small number of global variables?